# Which machine learning model to choose?

Tags: neural-network, data-mining, linear-regression, cross-validation, data-science-model

I am a beginner in data science. I am facing the problem of choosing the most appropriate algorithm for my specific problem.  I am building a recommendation system that gives students insight into whether or not a student qualifies for a certain study by comparing the information of that student to historical data about drop-out students of the previous 5 years that followed the same study at the same university. I am going to use these variables as input:  Gender, Age, Ethnicity, a median of previous grades of the student, Study disability, Income of parents, Graduated parents.
I would like to predict the drop-out rate of a specific student.
Which machine learning algorithm is the most appropriate for building such as recommendation system?

Comment: Are you doing this as a private project, or are you actually planning to present this to students?

Comment: Nobody could answer this questions as presented. Is you goal most accurate model? The fastest model? Most transparent model? How much time do you have to build this model? Generally people try different models, and see which ones work best. Also don't underestimate the value of data preparation.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is offtopic, but this time I have to comment the task.

I am commenting the project, in case you really want to apply this for students.

I think is it very dangerous to the society in general, if people that are "beginner in data science" create ML models that work on topics that are ethnical critical and highly biased, especially if ML is considered as black-box application.

If  people relied on this prediction, it would amplify the bias effect. So there is a big responsibilty involved in such projects.

Accordingly, such critical projects need to be designed carefully and in a proper way. To accomplish that, a comprehensive knowledge into the topic is necessary!
You need to understand the data, the model,  how much you can rely on the model and what implications you can deduce from the model.

Therefore, tackling this task simply by asking the internet "swarm intelligence" is not the right way to do. Machine learning may look like simple black-box application, but there is in fact more that needs to be understood before knowing what one can do to get reasonable and interpretable results.

So the only way to approach this task in a proper way is to study the relevant fields, including linear algebra, analysis, statistics, optimization, numerical analysis.

Comment: ".... is to study the relevant fields, including math, statistics and machine learning", machine learning is not a separate subject rather its applied statistics and nothing more..

Comment: well it takes usage of many techniques, e.g. also optimiziation theory. I have clarified the sentence in an update

Comment: Also, this was refering to the fact to many machine learning curses nowadays present common machine learning algorithms without properly presenting the underlying statistical theory.. So you can apply machine learning nowadays without understanding statistics